Why Do I Need to Retrain Model in Jetson Nano Projects After Kernel Restart or Device Shutdown?
I've been diving into the "Getting Started with AI on Jetson Nano" course and got my environment all sorted out using Docker. However, I've hit a snag - it seems like every time I restart the kernel in JupyterLab or power down my Nano, I end up having to retrain the model for my projects from scratch.
I'm a bit stumped as to why this keeps happening. It feels like either the trained models aren't persisting properly or there's an issue with how my environment is set up. I'm not sure where to even begin troubleshooting this.
Here's what I've done so far:
Went through the "Getting Started with AI on Jetson Nano" course of NVIDIA® Deep Learning Institute (DLI)
Got my environment up and running using Docker.
Noticed the annoying need to retrain the model after every kernel restart or device shutdown.
If anyone has any insights or tips on how to tackle this issue, I'd be incredibly grateful. Thanks a bunch!

You did not include any code, so there is not much to provide help, clearly you are not saving or loading the models correctly.

Thank you for your response. I am actually saving and loading the model, but I still face the issue.
Here is a part of my code where I save and load the model:
def load_model():
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(modelPath))
def save_model(c):
torch.save(model.state_dict(), model_path_widget.value)
modelPath = model_path_widget.value

The model file (my_model.pth) is created and appears in the directory, so it seems to be saved correctly. You can see the model file here.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G2I3gNFz72RIKmJjP13raJugpQLt7TIK/view?usp=share_link
